# Setting up Catch-All mail address on *nix

Tags: email

Warning: I'm a total *nix n00b. I need to get "catch-all" mail setup on OpenBSD. I'm just using the pre-installed mail service. Especially I want mail sent to `abc-123-def-geh@localhost' to redirect to 'user@localhost'. Is there a way using the pre-installed stuff or do I need some other software? If so: any suggestions on light-weight, easily configured software?

Answer (score 2):

If the pre-installed service is Postfix or Sendmail, you should be able to edit the `/etc/mail/aliases` file to your liking. It is in the format of:

`[alias name]:[existing account]`

So, to create the alias you need, you would edit the file to include:

`abc-123-def-geh: user`

And then, as root, run the `newaliases` command.

You can also define groups in this way, and more. See `man 5 aliases`. Most mail is by default sent to root, so you will probably want to define an alias for root as well.

Comment: Hum, but I want "catch all" which means I don't know the target email beforehand. I think I'm on to something though...

Answer (score 0):

I installed postfix (wasn't *that* hard but took a couple of hours), added a "catch-all" alias in /etc/postfix/virtual. Done - ta-daa! ;)

And, I had to kill sendmail before starting postfix to be able to run postfix for smtp as well (required for local catch-all unit tests).